# Problem using "Heart Rate" sensor in developing app by android simulator

Tags: android

I have tested **"Pressure"** and **"Acceleration"** sensors on simulator and all are working good, but I have problem with **"Heart Rate"** sensor.
I'm using code below to get "Heart" sensor object to get value:

```
sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE)
```

Also I'm checking FEATURE_SENSOR_HEART_RATE on device created by simulator by this code below but result is "false" :

```
hasHeartRateSensor = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_HEART_RATE);
```

I'm using :
Java 17 - Intellij 2023 - OS for android simulator is => Android wearOS3 android 11 or 9

this pic could help too..
[myPic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgPF4.png)

Is there any special way to make it to work?!!
any help pls...

I have tried other sensors and get value but "Heart" sensor dosen't work for me.